# Get Json arrays values in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have defined a json array in a file as

```
{
    mainServiceBar= [
        { "mainServiceName":"ECONOMIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"23.2" },
        { "mainServiceName":"SOCIAL SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"34.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEFENSE" , "mainServiceValue":"4.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"GENERAL PUBLIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"19" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEBT BURDEN" , "mainServiceValue":"18.8" },
    ];


    subServiceBar1: [
        { "subServiceName":"agriculture" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"trade" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"tourism" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"power and energy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"water resource" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" }
        { "subServiceName":"communication roads" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" }
        { "subServiceName":"other economic services" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"subsidy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
    ];
}
```

now i want these json arrays values in a javascript function , I have done few things but it I didn't get the values , my code is as follows :

```
function getJsonArray() {
    return $.getJSON("myjson.js"); 
}

function socialservice(thisv) {
    json = getJsonArray();

    for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var item = json[key];

            alert(item.mainServiceName);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

****EDITED**
I have also tried this  :

```
$.getJSON("myjson.json", function(data) {
    alert("val");

    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

but it do\esn't alert anything means it do not get json data

It alerts undefined , Please suggest me some way to get the values , Thanks

Comment: incorrect json provided

Comment: It is true that the json is incorrect but the function to read the json is also incorrect, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change your json file to below (it was wrongly formatted)

```
{
    mainServiceBar: [
        { "mainServiceName":"ECONOMIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"23.2" },
        { "mainServiceName":"SOCIAL SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"34.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEFENSE" , "mainServiceValue":"4.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"GENERAL PUBLIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"19" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEBT BURDEN" , "mainServiceValue":"18.8" }
    ],
    subServiceBar1: [
        { "subServiceName":"agriculture" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"trade" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"tourism" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"power and energy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"water resource" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"communication roads" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"other economic services" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"subsidy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" }
    ]
}
```

also change the socialservice function code to below it was wrongly retrieving the values :

```
function socialservice(thisv) {
    $.getJSON("myjson.js", function(json) {
        for (key in json) {
          $.each(json[key], function(k, arrayItem) {
            alert(arrayItem.mainServiceName);
          });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

call the function with `socialservice();` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Still function didn't alert anything (didn't go inside this $.getJSON( "myjson.js", function( json ) { })

Comment: this might sound silly but did you call the function ? try the new code.

Comment: Yes , I have . Infact alert outside this $.getJSON() is working but not inside

Comment: the only reason I can think of is that the json (js) file is not in the right place.

Comment: may be , but its in the same directory , let me define full path to file

Answer (score 1):

Accordin with [getJson doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you should write a callback in order to manipulate the data.

```
$.getJSON( "myjson.js", function( json ) {
    for (var key in json) {
          // code
    }
});
```

NB: Your JSON code posted is invalid. There are a lot of errors.
Try to replace with this:

```
{
    "mainServiceBar": [
        { "mainServiceName":"ECONOMIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"23.2" },
        { "mainServiceName":"SOCIAL SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"34.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEFENSE" , "mainServiceValue":"4.5" },
        { "mainServiceName":"GENERAL PUBLIC SERVICES" , "mainServiceValue":"19" },
        { "mainServiceName":"DEBT BURDEN" , "mainServiceValue":"18.8" }
    ],
    "subServiceBar1": [
        { "subServiceName":"agriculture" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"trade" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"tourism" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"power and energy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"water resource" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"communication roads" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"other economic services" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" },
        { "subServiceName":"subsidy" , "subServiceValue":"12.5" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried that to but , it didn't go inside this  , I have edited my question please check

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
function getJsonArray(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'myjson.js',
        type: 'GET',
        success : socialservice
    })
}


function socialservice(data){

json= data;
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var item = json[key];
    alert(item.mainServiceName); }}
return false;
  }
```